I am having issues with my build.gradle files (I think) in my flutter project
I think it is due to java, kotlin, gradle compatibility but I can't seem to figure out which versions to use exactly. I am also getting errors from firebase auth regarding these compatibility issues.
Here's the error i get when I "flutter run"
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> Failed to run Gradle Worker Daemon
   > A problem occurred starting process 'Gradle Worker Daemon 15'


My android/build.gradle file looks like this
buildscript {
//    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.10'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.20'
  //  ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0' // or whichever is the latest version you've upgraded to
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
       

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    }
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '21'
        }
    }

}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


my app/build.gradle looks like this
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    } 
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.assetyug"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21

    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '21'
    }




    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.assetyug"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}



And here's my gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists


If anyone could hop on a quick call with me to help. Please let me know
I have tried editing the build.gradle files to use:

Using different Java versions (mainly 17, and 21)
Gradle 8.5, 8.3, 8.7, 7.3
jvmTarget = 17, 21, 1.8


What Flutter version are you using?
